# how to get selected value from combox in windows c#

Tags: c#, window

I am new in windows. I want to get selected item on index changed in combobox in windows c#, at page load it calls selectedindexchanged event. how it happens. so plz help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: what page load? are you talking about ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example :

```
int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem.ToString() + "\n" +
                "Index: " + selectedIndex.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\n" +
                            "Index: " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        }
```